# Aligning images and text in a row

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site which has a 'meet the team' page. The 'team' section has two rows with 3 sets of images with text underneath. I want the rows aligned one under the other but at the minute I can't make this happen. 
here's the code snippet -

```css
.container {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
}

#team div.row {

 height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 
}

section#team .four {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  
 
}
```

```html
<section id="team">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                             <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns">
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
                                </p> 
                        </div>        
                        <div class="four columns">
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
                                </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>    
                </div>
                
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
                                <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </section>
```

Do I need the four columns for each image? Will they align along the row with a display rule? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try setting `float:left` on `.column img`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox does the trick.

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
}

section#team .row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

section#team .row .four {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
          <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus
            nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
          <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus
            nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
          <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus
            nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
          <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus
            nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
          <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus
            nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four columns">
          <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/hot-air-balloon.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
          <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus
            nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: My site shows the image just slightly off-center on top of the text, why might this be? (otherwise perfect btw ;) )

Comment: Images can be a pain. Is there a URL I can look at? If the images all have the same dimensions, I can possibly recreate here.

Comment: For the site? No its on a local server at the moment. I could try and apply some rules for the img?

Comment: If they all have the same dimensions, I can recreate here. Just let me have the width and height.

Comment: Its on the html above 100px X 100px but I also have a 50% border-radius.

Comment: I gave the containers a border, easier to see. Can't see any slippage here, but hey, I'm not 18 anymore. Maybe my eyes get a little fuzzy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150082/discussion-between-gerard-and-mike-whitehead).

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to display like you want:
more info at: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Aply flex property to the parent container of the items you want to align.

```
    #team div.row {

    height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;

}
```